# How does Victor Stone (Cyborg) replace lost body parts/material

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, cyborg, dc-animated-movie-universe

There not much I could do for research on this, but it is a rather simple question with possibly a complicated answer.

In Justice league Victor Stone (Cyborg) shoots a missile out of his arm that is constructed from the material that he is made of. Now considering that he is a Cyborg this is entirely an acceptable scenario.

But, what I want to know is how he regenerates that lost material?

Being that the comic Victor Stone (Cyborg) consists of nanites and robotics, do the nanites reconstuct the matrial lost or is it a more magical process?

### So how does Victor Stone (Cyborg) regenerate that lost material?

I don't mind an answer from any DC universe.

Comment: Is there a reason not to assume he has some limited store of missiles, etc habitually loaded up that just need to be replaced once used?

Comment: @Megha, If that is the case then an answer will address that. I am open to anything.

Comment: I am unaware if anyone has ever put this question to bed by mentioning this in an official DC release, but the DC wiki shows 3 possible abilities with sources that would fall in line with replenishment: Adaptive Countermeasures, Material Assimilation, and Nanobionic Regeneration. The way I see it regeneration would be the closest bet. If you can regenerate a piece of your body that is missing then what is to say a missile is not a piece of his normal state at this point?